# Elmah logs in self hosted rest application

Tags: .net, rest, console-application, elmah

I am having a console application which invokes services from a self hosted rest api project(say `http://localhost:8000/restapi`).

In the rest api project, Elmah is being used to log any exceptions.

Now, when I am accessing the service from the console application, and if there are some exceptions Elmah is not logging it !

Note that when the Rest Api is being hosted in IIS, and the service is invoked from there, the Elmah logging works fine.

Can somebody please suggest ?

Config of the rest API

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <httpHandlers> 
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers> 

    <httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>

    <elmah>
      <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
    </elmah>

    <system.web>
    <httpModules>
       <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
       <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
       <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
       <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
       <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Show your config file.

Comment: @David You mean config file of the RestApi project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some clues from [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api) and [there](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api)

I had missed to configure the Error logging filter, before invoking Web API from the console application

here are the missing bits -

```
var config = HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8000");
config.Filters.Add(new MyElmahErrorLoggingFilter());
var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
```

Comment: There seems to be a few more missing bits.